# How do I isolate a group of classes for reuse?

Tags: c#, module

I have a solution with some classes which I would like to isolate them in ordem to reuse them in another solution. I am new in C# and I don´t know if I should consider it as a library. I just want to organize them in a separated module. How to procedure? Create a class library? Define a new solution with the classes I want to isolate?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think this is too broad. As seen, there are two concise answers that propose the same solution (one that I agree with).

Comment: Just because it is a basic question doesn't mean it is a bad one.

Comment: Utility classes which are used now and them can be stored in a non project folder.  To include one, **Add Class | Existing Item**. Then navigate to it, but before you open it, the Add button is a drop down button - select **Add As Link**.  Changes you might make to it, are saved to it back in that isolated folder.  It keeps you from having multiple copies in multiple folders each with minor changes to them.  For stuff you use regularly, a class lib is ideal

Comment: Thanks to everyone who helped me here. Yes, I know this is a basic question and I really did some research before asking. I just wanted make sure what to do. I guess it always good to "hear" from experienced people. I am new using C# and VS.

Answer (score 1):

You would create a separate Class Library project. If the classes are closely related to another project then you might put them in the same solution as that project. But keeping them in a separate project means that it will build its own assembly (.dll) that you can reference from other projects.

One example is when creating a WCF service we might add a separate project in that solution containing the interfaces that the services implement and the input/output models that they use. That project is in the same solution as the WCF service and the WCF service references it. Then, if another project needs to interact with that WCF service it only references the interface assembly.

Answer (score 1):

If you want **reuse** it in another project, You should create Class Library and share it, like in this picture "**core**" is shared library between "**App1**" and "**App2**"

[image]